# Scripting date format

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting

I am trying to read a date from a cell for example `28-Jun-19` in cell A1, `17/01/2019` in cell A2 and write it to another sheet through script. The format I need is "mm/dd/yy" but my output is `6/28/2019, 12:00:00 AM`.

```
  A1           A2
------       --------
28-Jun-19   17/01/2019
```

I have not included the loops in the codes below:-

```
var A_Date = targetSheet1.getRange(lastRow -i, 2).getValues().toLocaleString();

sourceSheetalpha.getRange(lastRow2 + 1, 13).setValue(A_Date);
```

I expected output `28/06/2019`
I expected output `17/01/2019`

Comment: I cannot understand about the situation of `I expected output "28/06/2019" I expected output "17/01/2019"`. So can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Ok let me clear a tittle bit. Date that I want to read from a cell could be in any format either "17-Jan-19" or "17/01/2019". However, I only want out in "dd/mm/yy" which should be "17/01/2019". Let me know if you still have any confusion then I will share deck.

Comment: By supposing that the value of `17/01/2019` is the date object, I proposed 2 sample scripts. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and those were not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve value (date) from cell and put the value to the cell.
- The value is like `17/01/2019`.

  - From `my output is "6/28/2019, 12:00:00 AM".`, I thought that `17/01/2019` is the date object.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

In the following sample scripts, it supposes that `17/01/2019` is put in the cell "A1". And the retrieved value is put to the cell "B1" and "C1".

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `Utilities.formatDate()` is used.

#### Sample script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(Utilities.formatDate(value, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

- The retrieved value is put to the cell "B1".

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `setNumberFormat()` is used.

#### Sample script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

sheet.getRange("C1").setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").setValue(value);
```

- The retrieved value is put to the cell "C1".

#### References:

- [formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format)
- [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- [setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)
- [Number format tokens](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_tokens)

### Edit:

From your shared Spreadsheet, it was found that the values of `19-Jul-19` and `7/19/2019` are the date objects.

The script included in your shared Spreadsheet is as follows.

#### Your script:

```
function Test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheetOne = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sourceSheetOne.getLastRow();

   for (var i = 0 ; i < 12; i++)
   {
     var A_Date = sourceSheetOne.getRange(lastRow -i, 1).getValues().toString();
     sourceSheetOne.getRange(lastRow - i, 4).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").setValue(A_Date);

   }
}
```

In this case, unfortunately, my answer is not reflected. So please modify as follows.

#### Pattern 3:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var A_Date = sourceSheetOne.getRange(lastRow -i, 1).getValues().toString();
```

To:

```
var A_Date = sourceSheetOne.getRange(lastRow -i, 1).getValue();
```

#### Pattern 4:

As other pattern, how about the following script? I think that the process cost of this script is lower than that of above.

Script:

```
function Test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheetOne = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sourceSheetOne.getLastRow();

  var values = sourceSheetOne.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 1).getValues();
  sourceSheetOne.getRange(2, 4, values.length, values[0].length).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: ok i tried both method and it did not work, therefore I have made a sample file which I am sharing here [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14flzRlVCz89TZ53iZKpClebneULc4o0K68ugulpywKA/edit?usp=sharing] please send access request I will allow permission.

Comment: @Sharad Gurung Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I requested it.

Comment: I have provided access @Tanaike. Thank you.

Comment: @Sharad Gurung Thank you for sharing it. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that didn't work, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly!! well I am trying to understand what I was doing wrong, Thank you again!!

Comment: @Sharad Gurung Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.